# Deleting entry in one table deletes entire row in another table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In my application I have a class called Category and Post. If I delete a Category a Post with that same Category name gets deleted.

This information isn't useful without some code.

In the Category class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Post> posts;
```

In the Post class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
private Category category;
```

In the Category controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    categoryRepository.delete(id);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/categories");
}
```

Again, deleting a category (or executing the controller method above) deletes the category which is desired but it also deletes the entire post.

```
mysql> select * from category;
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | user_id |
+----+------+---------+
|  2 | a    |       1 |
+----+------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from post;
+----+-----------+------------+---------+-------------+---------+
| id | completed | date       | message | category_id | user_id |
+----+-----------+------------+---------+-------------+---------+
|  2 |         0 | 2016-04-04 | post    |           2 |       1 |
+----+-----------+------------+---------+-------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: It's because you have cascade.all. if you want to get child objects deleted on parent deletion we use cascade=CascadeType.ALL to @OneToMany but in your case you don't need that.

Comment: Try changing your Cascade type to save-update

Comment: I noticed this too. I tried removing the cascade all together but this generated a foreign key constraint error. What is the annotation for save update? I tried cascade = CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE.

Comment: It is what you mentioned

Comment: Unfortunately it is not recognized. It is also not part of the CascadeType enum when I opened the implementation.

Comment: What all enums u have?

Comment: Are u using the below org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade, with CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE

Comment: Use `cascade={PERSIST, MERGE, REFRESH, DETACH}`.  This will prevent the delete operation from cascading to the associated entity.

Comment: If you have a foreign key on category_id in the posts table, you won't be able to delete that category until all posts having that category_id are deleted first